# White borders around image

Tags: android, android-imageview, alphablending, alpha-transparency

How do i remove white borders around an image when used on different backgrounds?

[image]

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f4ef24e03431bbe4/ce7f19488fd0388a?lnk=gst&q=Crop+Image+View+that+fits+to+the+image#ce7f19488fd0388a

Comment: please phrase your question, so that other users could read and find out what u want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to use it as the main screen background then set its layout weight and height to "fill_parent" then the background can be any image you want it to be ref just like the SRC call you made.  That would let the image fill the screen only and give you access to write on the screen with the SCR command.  If you give us more of what your doing we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have seen the image and you want the ImageView to be *of the same shape* as your image because you don't want to see the white border around your image.

Well,in short, I don't think **that is possible** AFAIK. ImageView is a rectangular view which asks for height,width.

However, rather than try to do the impossible, I would suggest you to use **alpha-masking**( subset of alpha blending, google them to know more).

**A little theory:**   depending on the alpha bits for each pixel in your Bitmap (the translucency bits), the extent of blending of that pixel with over-written pixel is determined. Considering extremes, if alpha is 255, overwriting pixel is used instead of  the over-written one (**fully opaque**, in regular terms); if alpha is 0, overwriting pixel is just ignored (**transparent**). For other alphas in between: there is blending.

In your case you *would* have to make the alpha of the border **zero**, to achieve complete blend. Outlining the steps:.

1. The drawable to be used **can't** be a JPEG( JPEG doesn't store alpha values per pixel). Go for PNGs

   2.You **will need** to create and keep your bitmap drawable in that way beforehand(use google for alpha blending PNGs) such that the borders have zero alpha value ( use softwares like Paint.NET for ex).
2. If images are being created dynamically, you would need to use a blending equation ( for details read materials by Porter and Duff).

   For ex, this is PNG image with transparent pixels having alpha 0 other than the alphabet itself
   .
   [image: original PNG with alpha blending]

[image: aplha blended PNG on colored background]

Above is the alpha blended PNG on colored background of an Activity. I hope this is what you really want to achieve, and my answer is actually useful .